# Fechar a pagina webView depois de carregar

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

Estou utilizando a webView no iOS para acessar uma página web dentro de um aplicativo nativo utilizando a linguagem objective-c como no exemplo a seguir:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.exemplo.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Porém eu gostaria que a página depois de carregada completamente se fechasse automaticamente sem a necessidade do usuário interferir. Eu ja procurei na documentação do NSURL, porém não encontrei algo que me ajudasse nessa questão.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, acrescente em seu arquivo de cabeçalho `.h` a classe *delegate* referente ao `UIWebView`:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

E assim, na implementação defina a propriedade do seu `UIWebView`:

```
[_webView setDelegate:self];
```

E por fim, o método *delegate* que irá realizar a ação que você desejar, assim que a página for carregada:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Ação ao carregar página...
}
```

Por "fechar a página", eu não entendi bem qual exatamente esta ação que você deseja, mas acredito que a partir deste método você pode definir.

Comment: Dexia eu ver se entendi, no momento em que o método *webViewDidFinishLoad* é chamado, quer dizer que o carregamento da página terminou? Exemplificando, se tenho uma imagem na página em que estou acessando, esse método será chamado quando toda imagem for carregada na página?

Comment: @JonathanGonczoroski, esse método será chamado quando a página inteira for carregada, se por um acaso, essa página só for uma imagem, quando acabar de carregar a imagem ele será chamado.

Answer (score 0):

Além de usar o método delegate da webView : webViewDidFinishLoad

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     // Ação chamada ao terminar de carregar a página...

    // Recomendo adicionalmente uma ação para ser executada automaticamente após alguns segundos depois de carregada a pagina, seja para ocultar a webview ou apresentar uma mensagem ao usuário dizendo que foi com sucesso.
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideWebView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
```

Use também o método do delegate para tratar as situações de erro de carga da página!

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //Trate os possíveis erros da carga da url aqui.
}
```